# sudo: command not found when changing the permissions of a directory

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo

I want to execute this command `sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat`, but I get :

```
No command '​sudo' found, did you mean:
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
 Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
sudo: command not found
```

How should I change permissions in this case?

Comment: Does `sudo` fail only when running `chgrp`, or does it always fail?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: only when running `chgrp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several possibilities:

1. Install `sudo` by `apt-get install sudo` (run it from root account)
2. Run as root user `su -c "chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat"`

Comment: I have sudo installed. This is the issue of permissions. I changed permissions to the folder `opt` and now I have several issues. For example I cannot open `localhost/phpmyadmin`. It says that permissions are too broad (I set 777).

Comment: Change it back to what it should be, which is 755